# Merge 1min, 5min and Daily OHLC dataframes WITHOUT upsampling the 1min?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, alpha-vantage

To make this simple, let's say I have 3 datasets, a 1min OHLCV dataset, a 5min, and a Daily. Given these 3 datasets:

1min

[image: 1min]

5min

[image: 5min]

Daily

[image: Daily]

...how can I merge them and turn them into something like this using Pandas/Python 3?

[image: DesiredOutcome]

As you can see, every time a new 5 mins is hit going down the 1min dataframe, the matching time from the 5min chart <= the 1min time gets added to their respective columns. I've left the blanks in there to help visualize what's happening, but for simplicity's sake, I can just forward fill the values. No backfilling so as to not introduce a lookahead bias. The daily value would be the previous day's OHLCV data, except for 4:00 PM, that would be the current day's data. This is because of how Alpha Vantage structures their dataframes. I also have a 15min and 60min dataset to go along with this, but I think once the 1 to 5min merge is done, the same logic could apply.

I have included a reproducible code below to get the exact dataframes I'm working with, however you have to `pip install alpha_vantage` and get a free API key from [here](https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key).

SIMPLE DESIRED SOLUTION - What I've outlined above.

ADVANCED DESIRED SOLUTION - Rather than forward filling the 5min data, ideally those empty spaces would consist of the respective running prices. For example, the next empty open price in the 5min_open column would be the same 1min_open at the beginning of that 5 minutes. Think of something like:

```
conversion = {'Open' : 'first', 'High' : 'max', 'Low' : 'min', 'Close' : 'last', 'Volume' : 'sum'}
```

That way the empty spaces in the 5min columns are updating as they should, but the simple solution would suffice.

I don't want to just upsample the 1min dataframe because I want to include all of the previous data from a past daily dataframe, so to upsample the 1min to a daily dataset, I'd lose a bunch of past daily data, so I want the solution to NOT include upsampling, but merging of different df's by datetime. Thanks!

Windows 10, Python 3:

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import pandas as pd
import sys, os
import os.path
from time import sleep

# Make a historical folder if it's not created already
if not os.path.exists("data/historical/"):
    os.makedirs("data/historical/")

api_call_limit_daily = 500

total_api_count = 0

timeframes = ['1min','5min','15min','60min','daily']

ts = TimeSeries(key='YOUR_API_KEY_HERE', output_format='csv')

tickers = ['SPY']

for ticker in tickers:

    # Ensure uppercase
    ticker = str(ticker.upper())

    for timeframe in timeframes:

        print("Downloading dataset for", ticker, "-", timeframe, "...")

        if total_api_count > api_call_limit_daily:
            print("Daily API call limit reached. Closing...")
            sys.exit(0)

        if timeframe != 'daily':
            data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday_extended(symbol=ticker, interval=timeframe)
        
        elif timeframe == 'daily':
            data, meta_data = ts.get_daily(symbol=ticker)
            
        # Convert the data object to a dataframe, and reverse the order so oldest date's on top
        csv_list = list(data)
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(csv_list[1:], columns=csv_list[0])
        data = data.iloc[::-1]
        if timeframe == 'daily':
            data = data.rename(columns={"timestamp": "time"})
        print(data)
        df = data.set_index('time')
        total_api_count += 1

        df.to_csv("data/historical/" + ticker + "_" + timeframe + ".csv", index=True)
        print("Success...")

        # Sleep if we're not through tickers/timeframes yet re: api limits
        sleep(15)

print("Done!")
```

**UPDATE**

I have frankenstein'd an iterative process for the simple solution that works for each dataframe, except for the daily. Still trying to work that out. Basically for any time on the 1min rows, I want to display YESTERDAY's daily data, unless the time is >= 16:00:00, then it can be the current day's. I want that so not to introduce forward peaking. Anyway, here's the code that accomplishes what I'm looking for iteratively, but hoping there's a faster/cleaner way to do this:

```
import numpy as np
# Merge all timeframes together into one dataframe
for ticker in tickers:

    # Ensure uppercase
    ticker = str(ticker.upper())

    for timeframe in timeframes:

        # Define the 1min timeframe as the main df we'll add other columns to
        if timeframe == "1min":
            main_df = pd.read_csv("./data/historical/" + ticker + "_" + timeframe + ".csv")
            main_df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(main_df['time'])
            continue

        # Now add in some nan's for the next timeframe's columns
        main_df[timeframe + "_open"] = np.nan
        main_df[timeframe + "_high"] = np.nan
        main_df[timeframe + "_low"] = np.nan
        main_df[timeframe + "_close"] = np.nan
        main_df[timeframe + "_volume"] = np.nan

        # read in the next timeframe's dataset
        df = pd.read_csv("./data/historical/" + ticker + "_" + timeframe + ".csv")
        df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

        # Rather than doing a double for loop to iterate through both datasets, just keep a counter
        # of what row we're at in the second dataframe. Used as a row locater
        curr_df_row = 0

        # Do this for all datasets except the daily one
        if timeframe != 'daily':

            # Iterate through the main_df
            for i in range(len(main_df)):

                # If the time in the main df is >= the current timeframe's row's df, add the values to their columns
                if main_df['time'].iloc[i] >= df['time'].iloc[curr_df_row]:

                    main_df[timeframe + "_open"].iloc[i] = df['open'].iloc[curr_df_row]
                    main_df[timeframe + "_high"].iloc[i] = df['high'].iloc[curr_df_row]
                    main_df[timeframe + "_low"].iloc[i] = df['low'].iloc[curr_df_row]
                    main_df[timeframe + "_close"].iloc[i] = df['close'].iloc[curr_df_row]
                    main_df[timeframe + "_volume"].iloc[i] = df['volume'].iloc[curr_df_row]

                    curr_df_row += 1

    # Daily dataset logic would go here

    print(main_df)
    main_df.to_csv("./TEST.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Since your question is not about accessing the API, I would suggest to instead provide an code example (that can be copied and run) using some sample data (defined as code) that illustrate your problem. Then defining the exact desired output, for the provided sample data will greatly help anyone, who might be able to help you.

Comment: @de1 I thought of this too, but anyone with an AV api can just run this right away, else anyone with datasets of their own can help as they can be downloaded through yfinance easily enough. Kinda looking for help from people in this domain as they can tell what I'm trying to accomplish, and would have OHLCV datasets handy already :P